# Facebook graph api filtering nested object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to filter by `creativeid` on `Ads` using facebook graph api.

I tried below query but it is not working.

1. `act_xxxxxx/ads?fields=creative{id}&filtering=[{field: "creative",operator:"EQUAL", value:"id_of_creative"}]`
2. `act_xxxxxx/ads?fields=creative{id}&filtering=[{field: "ad.creative.id",operator:"EQUAL", value:"id_of_creative"}]`
3. `act_xxxxxx/ads?fields=creative{id}&filtering=[{field: "creative.id",operator:"EQUAL", value:"id_of_creative"}]`

But for all above response is

`{ "error": { "message": "(#100) Filtering field 'creative.' with operation 'equal' is not supported", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100, "error_data": "An unknown error occurred", "fbtrace_id": "AlWsddsx" } }`